# How to pre-check Facebook checkbox plugin?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

The Facebook checkbox plugin precheck attribute is not working properly.

HTML:

```
<div class="fb-messenger-checkbox"
     origin="https://example.com"
     page_id="XXXXXXXXXXX"
     messenger_app_id="XXXXXXXXXXX"
     user_ref="<? echo $random_val?>"
     prechecked="true"
     allow_login="true"
     size="large">
</div>
```

How may I fix this?

Comment: Your markup looks broken. you can't place <br/> within an HTML tag.

Comment: What's the value of `$random_val`?

Comment: $random_val = Random user_ref string, All other functionality works fine only problem with precheck

Answer (score 2):

> How may I fix this?

Not at all, because https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/checkbox-plugin:

> Customizing Default State
>
> While historically it was possible to customize the default state of the checkbox plugin, beginning October 6, 2017, the default state of the checkbox plugin will be unchecked only. Websites that implemented the plugin before this date will still be able to select checked as the default state.

Comment: Thanks for replying CBroe! Is there any way to check it when rendering on page with jquery?

Comment: No. Same Origin Policy prevents you from interacting with the plugin content. Plus, if Facebook wanted you to be able to pre-check it, they probably would not have removed the option in the first place - so any attempts of yours in that regard could be considered a policy violation.

Comment: Okay understood. Thank You CBroe

Comment: Can we make it like once user check this checkbox manually than every time it is coming checked.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a way.  I'm not sure how intensive it would be to develop this yourself, but there is a third party plugin that does it.  I tested it out and so far it's been working flawlessly.  Facebook didn't give my store pre-check by default either, so we've seen a huge increase in sales because of it.

The plugin/website is called AlwaysChecked.  Not sure if links are allowed, so just add a dot com after it.  It works for shopify, woocommerce, etc.  Sorry I could not provide more detailed information on how to code it yourself, but here is a solution nonetheless.